# Problema ao salvar acento com Entity Framework e PostgreSQL

Tags: c#, entity-framework, postgresql, entity-framework-6, wpf

Preciso fazer a migração de um sistema com banco de dados SQLSERVER para um PostGreSQL 9.3. Nunca trabalhei com PostGre antes então estou usando o Entity Framework 6 com model-first para facilitar o processo. A aplicação de migração está sendo desenvolvida em WPF. Minhas duas primeiras tabelas importaram tranquilamente, porém em um dos registros da terceira tabela é necessário ser inserido "**NÃO**".

IMPORTANTE: Não tenho a opção de inserir sem acento pois o sistema que usa a base do POSTGre é um sistema legado que só vai entender com acento. Em uma base de produção desse sistema está com acento e com a mesma configuração na imagem mais abaixo.

```
 // produtor rural
 if (objPessoa.pes_cliProdutorRural == true)
       objNovoCliente.produtorrural = "SIM";
 else
       objNovoCliente.produtorrural = "NÃO";

  // adicionar no contexto
  this.objCtxMSP2.tbcadclientes.Add(objNovoCliente);
  this.objCtxMSP2.SaveChanges();
```

Porém dá o seguinte erro no SaveChanges:

> InnerException = {"ERRO: 22001: valor � muito longo para tipo
>   character(3)"}

Pesquisando na internet vi que pode ser algo referente a "collation" e/ou "encoding".

Essa é a configuração atual do banco:

[image: Configuração do banco]

Ao tentar criar o banco com encoding LATIN1 como vi em outro fórum dá o seguinte erro

[image: inserir a descrição da imagem aqui]

Alguma ideia de como resolver isso?

Comment: É provavel que o seu ambiente (IIS) esteja em UTF8 e você esta tentando usar latin1 (que é compativel apenas com windows-1252 e iso-8859-1). Qual o seu preferido Latin1 ou Utf8?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Tive outro problema recentemente com o postgresql e npgsql, mas dessa vez postei no stackoverflow em inglês, conseguindo contato com o pessoal responsável, e vão soltar uma atualização que também deve resolver esse problema que é praticamente o mesmo. A correção estará na versão 3.1.8 do npgsql.

https://stackoverflow.com/questions/39145146/cannot-select-some-rows-with-npgsql-on-a-portuguese-database/39153317#39153317

Answer (score 3):

É provavel que o seu ambiente (IIS) esteja em UTF8 e você esta tentando usar `latin1` (que é compatível apenas com windows-1252 e iso-8859-1).

No caso se for usar Latin1 pode configurar o *web.config* assim:

```
<system.web>
     ...
     <globalization
         requestEncoding="iso-8859-1"
         responseEncoding="iso-8859-1"
         fileEncoding="iso-8859-1"
         culture="pt-BR"
         uiCulture="pt-BR" />
     ...
</system.web>
```

Se decidir migrar o banco pra utf8 (ou já estiver usando) então use assim:

```
<system.web>
     ...
     <globalization
         requestEncoding="utf-8"
         responseEncoding="utf-8"
         fileEncoding="utf-8"
         culture="pt-BR"
         uiCulture="pt-BR" />
     ...
</system.web>
```

> Os `...` são apenas pra dizer que é em qualquer lugar do XML, não copie eles.

Comment: esqueci de especificar que é WPF minha aplicação de importação. Mas compreendo sua resposta, vou ver se consigo configurar isso na minha aplicação WPF.

Comment: Tenho o mesmo problema com o NHibernate, vou verificar isso no web.config, obrigado!

Answer (score 0):

Se possível configurar seu *Entity* no `WebConfig` ou seu `OnModelCreating` setar a criação do banco numa forma que atenda essa instrução:

```
CREATE DATABASE nome_banco WITH OWNER = usuario_banco ENCODING = 'LATIN1' TABLESPACE = pg_default LC_COLLATE = 'C' LC_CTYPE = 'C' CONNECTION LIMIT = -1 TEMPLATE template0;
```